# Parsing Python Structure as PyObject

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-embedding

I'm returning object of following structure from a python function

```
class Bus(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ("a", c_int), 
                 ("b", c_char), 
                 ("c", c_float), 
                 ("d", c_double), 
                 ("e", c_char_p) 
               ]

def GetBus(  *args, **kwargs ):
    Signal = cast(c_char_p(kwargs['Bus']), POINTER(Bus )).contents
    ## Logic that updates Signal
    return Signal
```

---

In my C code, I want update my C struct `bus`, by parsing the `pValue`, obtained from :

```
  Bus bus ;
  python_Bus = Py_BuildValue("s#",  (char* )&bus,  sizeof(Bus)) ;
  PyDict_SetItemString( pDict,"Bus", python_Bus ) ;

  PyObject* pValue = PyObject_Call(pFunc, pArgs,pDict) ;
```

How to I parse `pValue` ?

Is there's any `Py???_???(pvalue, ???) ;` ? or How do I convert it to `char*` and do a `memcpy` in my C code (if that's a way) ?

---

I also tried creating a new Python Type, but looks like it all boiled down to `Py_BuildValue` in my "`getter`" function, and I don't want to have several "`setters`" for each element.

<sup>***Using Python2.7***</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `ctypes.Structure`, you could use the implementation of [Buffer interface](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#c.PyObject_GetBuffer).

Try something like:

```
Py_buffer view = { 0 };
PyObject_GetBuffer(pvalue, &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE);
// use view.buf, which is of void*
PyBuffer_Release(&view);
```

You might want to add some error handling to be sure of getting the proper data.

Comment: Thank you ! Works as expected. Also could you please comment if I'm passing my C `bus` _correctly_ to Python ? It works but I'd like to get comment if I'm doing anything goofy or there's any other good way

Comment: I would create a [new type](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) and use it on both sides. Why using ctypes at all?